# Result always on the bases of fix column qlikview expression

Tags: expression, qlikview

I have a table in that table there is ID column .. i want the result on the bases of that ID column .. when that ID column removed with the another dimension then result be should be same on the bases of ID column .. this is expression what i tried

```
 Aggr(rangemin(sum({<FO={'out'}>}claim),500),ID)
```

but this shows that when i replace another dimension with ID column figures is changed..

so how i fix this expression on the bases of ID dimension

any help

UPDATE

this is the link of test file

https://www.dropbox.com/s/p3nyy6h7iybrctu/test_id.rar?dl=0

in this test file i want data on the bases of ID in second table

Comment: Please add some example data and the desirable result

Comment: Kindly chekc link of test file